# Microsoft Access/SQL - Query to combine rows from incomplete tables

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have several data sources, each providing a piece of the truth. In order to understand the full picture, I need to be able to write a query that combines data from all of the sources into one table. The data I have is complicated so I'll provide a simple example to try to understand the concept.

I have Table1 and Table2  given. I need to combine them to fill in the blanks and create a master data source (Table3). Let's assume serial will always be provided.

Table1 (given)

```
serial1 name1   city1   country1    OS1
123     pc-123                      windows 7
124     pc-124  Tampa   US          Windows XP
125     pc-125  Sydney  AU          Windows 7
126             Tempe   US
```

Table2 (given)

```
serial2 name2   city2   country2    OS2
123     pc-123  Atlanta US          
124                     US          Windows XP
125                                 
126     pc-126                      Windows XP
```

Table3 (what I want to create)

```
serial  name    city    country     OS
123     pc-123  Atlanta US          windows 7
124     pc-124  Tampa   US          Windows XP
125     pc-125  Sydney  AU          Windows 7
126     pc-126  Tempe   US          Windows XP
```

Is there a simple union, left join, combination of SQL I can write to execute this? I have been looking thru the forums but couldn't find anything quite like this. Thanks in advance for any help here!

Comment: What if the data conflicts?

Answer (score 1):

If `serial` is unique (meaning you have 0..1 rows in each table per serial and they always correlate) and you don't care which value you get on conflicts, you can do something like:

```
SELECT serial, MAX(name) AS name, MAX(city) AS city, 
    MAX(country) AS country, MAX(OS) AS OS
FROM (
    SELECT serial1 AS serial, name1 AS name, city1 AS city, 
        country1 AS country, OS1 AS OS
    FROM Table1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT serial2 AS serial, name2 AS name, city2 AS city, 
        country2 AS country, OS2 AS OS
    FROM Table2
) AS x
GROUP BY serial
```

Comment: I'm getting an error - Circular reference cause by alias 'Name' in query definition's SELECT list. Any ideas?

Comment: Hmm...not sure why. Does the derived table query work by itself?

Comment: Avoid the circular reference error by not re-using the field name as the alias for the `Max()` expression.  `SELECT Max([name]) AS MaxOfName` ... and so forth.

Comment: thanks lc. for the solution and thanks HansUp for the fix. This solution is going to save me a lot of time and effort. If I wanted to add a third table and so on can I simply add another UNION ALL and SELECT statement?

Comment: Also, as you mentioned above, when the data conflicts which value will this code take? Looking at my actual data it seems to go back and forth.

Comment: @jthinson Yes, you can just add another UNION ALL SELECT. As for which value it takes, currently it's the lexically maximal value of each column (using the MAX function)

Comment: Great I got that to work as well. What if I wanted to connect a fourth table that connected on name instead of serial? Would that be possible with a simple change as well?

Comment: You would probably be better off doing that table after these ones